# Minimongoid vs. Simple Schema, Collection2, Autoform?

Tags: meteor

I'm building a new Meteor app and trying to decide between running with the Simple Schema/Collection2/Autoform trifecta (hereby referred to as Collection2) or using the alternative Minimongoid.

Collection2 seems to have much greater adoption, but it doesn't seem to have the same support for object relations (e.g. has_many, habtm, etc.) as minimongoid. Collection2 also has the potentially invaluable Autoform. Also, minimongoid hasn't been updated in over a month.

Thoughts? Experiences? When is one preferable to the other? What are the main differences/benefits/drawbacks?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is based on opinion, so here's my opinionated answer:

First of all, they are all the same and use the same underlying meteor methods to achieve the task. So it is better if you first get yourself acquainted with what meteor provides out of box.

If you come from an object oriented, orm fueled, fully relational world like java+sql, you may find yourself more comfortable with minimongoid conventions.

If you feel comfortable with embracing nosql conventions, and also like some utility to do some scaffolding for you, go with autoform.

I personally use collection2 (which also implies simple-schema) but don't use autoform since I like more fine-grained control over my ui. But what simple-schema and collection2 provide me out of box for data structuring and validation, while keeping flexibility, is invaluable.